# comparing emmeans estimate to null distribution

Tags: r, emmeans

Let's say I have this model

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=rexp(500, .01), x=rep(c("A","B"),each=250), id=rep(seq(1,250),times=2))
mod <- lmer(y~ x + (1|id), data=df)
```

If I calculate the mean effect of each level of `x`, it is very significant

```
test(emmeans(mod, ~ x))

     x emmean   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 A   98.4 5.66 496  17.394  <.0001
 B   92.6 5.66 496  16.360  <.0001
```

because presumably it's testing each effect against zero.
To make these tests meaningful, I suppose I need to create a null distribution using bootstrapping. For example for `x=="A"`, `replicate(10^4, mean(sample(df[df$x=="A","y"],n,rep=T)))` and then compare the estimate from `emmeans` to the values in this distribution?

What is the correct approach to do this with `emmeans`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in `emmeans` because there is no way to incorporate the details of the simulated distribution. `emmeans`'s tests are based on the normal approximation to sampling distribution of the *estimate*, and doesn't use any other distribution.

You can however test against a particular *value*. For example,

```
test(emmeans(mod, "x"), null = 90)
```

or if you want different null values for the respective means

```
test(emmeans(mod, "x"), null = c(90, 80))
```

If you use null values equal to the sample means, those are exactly equal to the EMMs in this example, and you will get P values of 1.